# How is hybrid (RSA+DH) more secure than RSA quantitatively?

Tags: encryption, rsa, hybrid-encryption

Is there any graph that serves as a comparative analysis for the factorization problem vs discrete logarithn problem? I am implementing an hybrid encryption algorithm (RSA + Diffie-Hellman) and it is necessary for me to show qualitatively that the hybrid (RSA+DH) is more secure than RSA.

Comment: Look at [www.keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/). It is not clear what do you mean with hybrid RSA and DHKE. Hybrid Cryptosystem is used to define key exchange with the public key cryptosystem like RSA (RSA-KEM) or DHKE (ECDHKE) then encrypt with symmetric cryptosystem like AES-GCM(-SIV) and (x)ChaCha20-Poly1305. Today, RSA mostly used for signature as in TLS 1.3.

Comment: Since Diffie-Hellman is not an _encryption algorithm_, I think "implementing an hybrid encryption algorithm (RSA + Diffie-Hellman)" makes some error in terminology. A _protocol_ with these ingredients is common practice.

Comment: RSAES-OAEP with 2048-bit key size can encrypt at most 190 bytes. RSA-KEM can't encrypt anything, but instead exchanges input key material and derives a shared key using a KDF. Mostly RSA is used only for signatures, not for encryption. It's slow to generate RSA keys, so they aren't practical for ephemeral use, while ECDH keys are. So you do an ECDH exchange, signing it to provide authentication, and then use an AEAD (possibly with some sort of key ratcheting) for the actual encryption.